# RDS data pipeline issue with Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, rds

I am facing an issue with the data transfer from RDS to Redshift table.
I have table1 on RDS where i have column "date" having date and time format value. Whenever my data got transferred from RDS to Redshift. I am getting the ".0" to appended at the last of that date value.

An eg.

Table1 column "date" have value "2018-01-03 08:15:05" in rds table, but when i checked after transferring through data pipeline in redshift.
In redshift the data of date column is like "2018-01-03 08:15:05.0"

So it means, data pipeline is effecting on something.

Any one have any idea !!

In table1 date column type is "timestamp"
and on redshift it is "varchar".

Looking forward to you guys !!

Thanks & Regards

Comment: its the same date as a string with 1 decimal place - just remove it

Comment: @JonScott But why it appending that !!

How to remove that one decimal place !!

Comment: it is going through a complex process of taking the source - mapping to an internal type and then mapping that out to redshift. unfortunately data pipeline is a bit flaky and poorly documented so sometimes you have to just go with it - or contact aws support?